# Batch converting 10.4 mxd files to 10.1 with ArcPy gives AttributeError: MapDocObject: Unable to save?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, attributeerror

Closely related to [Converting .mxd files that were created with 10.3 to .mxd files that are compatible with 10.1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210558), except I am running **ArcGIS 10.4**. It should be possible for me to make 10.1 copies of all my 10.4 mxds. Here is my code:

```
import arcpy, sys, os, string 

dir = r"D:\Path\To\Maps"
outloc = os.path.join(dir, "Compatible_MXDs")
version = '10.1'

suffix = "_"+ version.replace(".", "")

# Get all mxds in this directory
arcpy.env.workspace = dir
mxdList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")

for file in mxdList:
    print(file) # mymap.mxd
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(dir, file))
    base = os.path.basename(file)
    print(base)
    # ('D:/Path/To/Maps/mymap', '.mxd')
    base = os.path.splitext(base)[0] + suffix + os.path.splitext(base)[1] 
    mxd.saveACopy(outloc + os.sep + base, version)
    print(os.path.basename(file) + " has been converted")
```

But I get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "MakeMXDsBackwardsCompatible.py", line 21, in <module>
mxd.saveACopy(outloc + os.sep + base, version)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
return fn(*args, **kw)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\_mapping.py", line 877, in saveACopy
self._arc_object.saveACopy(file_name, version)
AttributeError: MapDocObject: Unable to save.  Check to make sure you have 
write access to the specified file and that there is enough space on the 
storage device to hold your document.
```

I'd rather not use the "File -> Save a Copy -> change mxd version" dialogue for 500 separate mxds over multiple directories.

---

While my question is also closely related to [AttributeError: MapDocObject: Unable to save on mxd.save/saveACopy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23087), the answers are still not satisfactory for my problem. The relevant (simplified) code:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\Path\To\Maps\mymap.mxd")

mxd.saveACopy(r"D:\Path\To\Maps\Compatible_MXDs\mymap_101.mxd", '10.1')
```

Now with regard to that question's answers...

1) I have no mxds with the same name already on disk, nor am I trying to overwrite.

2) I am not attempting to overwrite an mxd file that is already in use. No other scripts are concurrently accessing it. Furthermore nothing changes even after I add

```
del mxd
```

at the end.

3) Again, I am not calling anything like

```
mxd.saveACopy(mxd)
```

I have read the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/mapdocument-class.htm).

I have tried rebooting and running my script without starting ArcMap. I don't use an IDE, but use Notepad++ to write my scripts and execute them on my command line with `python MakeMXDsBackwardsCompatible.py`

Comment: To me that message suggests that something, probably an ArcMap instance, is holding a lock over one or more of your mxds.  Have you tried rebooting and then running your script from an IDE (without starting ArcMap)?

Comment: No instances of Arc were open while I tried running this. In the question you linked, the asker failed to pass the proper path parameter in mxd.saveACopy(...). I'm pretty sure I did this right.

Comment: That question has three answers so to get your question  re-opened you will need to [edit] it to account for why none of them apply to you. To me that message suggests that something is holding a lock over one or more of your mxds.  Have you tried rebooting and then running your script from an IDE (without starting ArcMap)?

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear. I have tried rebooting and running my script without starting ArcMap. I don't use an IDE, but use Notepad++ to write my scripts and execute them on my command line with 
"python MakeMXDsBackwardsCompatible.py"
Also I have edited my question to explain why those 3 answers do not help me. Can my question please be reopened? Thanks in advance!